# Why doesn't my data doesn't display in new row?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, pug

I am having problem with display checked checkboxes. How can I display each checkedbox in a new line? Because at the moment they are stacking beside eachother in same line.

```
b-modal#modal-1.d-flex(title='Dodaj leki' hide-footer)
        b-form-checkbox-group.mb-3(v-model='selected', :options='options', value-field='text', text-field='text', disabled-field='notEnabled')

 .row
        .col-md-4
          p.title Nazwa
        .col-md-4
          p.title Produkty zakazane
      .row.py-2
        .col-md-4
          span {{ selected }}
        .col-md-4
          span {{ forbiddenProducts }}
```

````
 selected: [],
      options: [
          { text: 'Cholesterol', value: 'cholesterol' },
          { text: 'Ciśnienie tętnicze', value: 'ciśnienie tętnicze' },
          { text: 'Kwas moczowy', value: 'kwas moczowy' },
          { text: 'Nadczynność tarczycy', value: 'nadczynność tarczycy' },
          { text: 'Przeciwzakrzepowe (acenokumarol)', value: 'przeciwzakrzepowe (acenokumarol)' },
          { text: 'Antykoncepcja hormonalna', value: 'Antykoncepcja hormonalna' },          
        ],
    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox by default are staggered one after the other.
To make each of them occupy a separate row, you can contain all of them in a div container and use the flexbox on that div.

**HTML**

```
<div class="modify">
  <input type="checkbox" name="a">
  <input type="checkbox" name="b">
  <input type="checkbox" name="c">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.modify{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are looking for **v-for** directive. Your code then would look something like this.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>
    <div v-for="option in options">
      {{option.text}}: <input type="checkbox" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="button">Add</div>
    <div class="button">Remove</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html